# How to check bound hotkeys in the system?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, key-binding

An application must have bound itself to the key combination of the "}" character on my machine, and I cannot write this character anymore. Is there an application to check the hot key bindings in the system? (I'm using Windows 7)